# Question age not calculated correctly

Tags: bug, status-declined, time

Today I stumbled upon this issue – on one of the question pages at Stack Overflow, it says:

> asked **1 year ago**

Yet below the little box says:

> asked May 3 '12 at 19:02

Correct me if I am wrong, but that doesn't seem right.

[image: Stats]
[image]

Comment: What is wrong?  It's still less than 2 years old.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. Am i completely bonkers, or has that value been given in months before?

Comment: We are a technical site, and this is *totally* inappropriate IMHO. Henceforth, we should devise a new system. Only round up to years whenever you're +/- 5 days from the year. And then, say "about X years ago"  . Else, list *exact* days. Ok so who does the coding around here? Please do this by noon tomorrow, and peace will prevail, donuts will blossom, coffee spilleth

Comment: As devnull said, it's 1 year ago if you round down.

Comment: @devnull - It's incorrect though. How could it be asked "1 year ago"  and also asked 682 days ago ? -  that means 365 = 682 ????? http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?m1=5&d1=3&y1=2012&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=682

Comment: @Adel `682 < 365 * 2`

Comment: @michaelb958 - Sure, but the rounding could be more useful. i.e why not "1 year, 8 months" ?

Comment: @Adel It's for simplicity.  Probably not worth it.

Comment: Well, it is definitely intended then, and not a bug. Thus the question is answered. But i would as well think it made more sense if the information was a bit more precise.

Comment: @InLak'esh. - Agreed .  Well, It may make sense to remove it altogether actually , because you can see the exact date. but at the same time, it seems it's intended as arough measure anyway.

Comment: I'd like to say, the rounding system in SO is quite... interesting. The age is rounded down, but the reputation is rounded up (in mobile, my SO rep is shown as 2k)

Comment: @AndrewT. The age is __truncated__ but the reputation in mobile is __rounded__.  If it's 4200, then it'd show up as 4k.

Comment: @Skliwz bug can't really be declined, [meta-tag:status-bydesign] fits better. :)

Comment: "1 year ago" means "more than one year and less than two years ago", once you get used to it, it stops being weird. :)

Comment: Does it really matter if it isn't perfect? You can look at the date anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The age as currently implemented would show up in:

- days if the question is less than 1 month old
- month if it's less than a year old
- years otherwise
- whatever unit that it is displayed in is truncated

This implies that if a question is 1 month and 27 days old, it'd show up as 1 month old.  Even a day short of 43 years, and it'd show up as 42 years old.

Comment: Can't they improve it a bit to be more accurate? let's say if it is more than 1 year and 6 months it would show like "More than 1 year" or "Almost 2 years"?